# How to pass to vue-js-modal dialog beforeOpen and beforeClose listeners?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For dialog window I used https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal. I need perform some code after closing dialog, so how can I pass beforeOpen and beforeClose listeners to dialog?

**Changes:**

I added  `@before-open="beforeOpen" @before-close="beforeClose"` to `<v-dialog>` and listed them in methods section, but still doesn't work

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title || 'Undefended'%}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <form id="form2" v-on:submit.prevent="login">
            <input type="email" v-model="signIn.email" placeholder="email@email.com">
            <input type="password" v-model="signIn.password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </form>

        <v-dialog @before-open="beforeOpen" @before-close="beforeClose"/>
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> main.js shorten version

```
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.use(VModal, {dialog: true});
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        signIn: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
    },

    methods: {
        beforeOpen: function () {
            console.log("open")
        },
        beforeClose: function () {
            console.log("close")
        },

        login: function () {
            fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.signIn.email, this.signIn.password)
                .then((user) => {
                    if (!user.emailVerified) {
                        //-------------dialog-------------//
                        this.$modal.show('dialog', {
                            title: 'Alert!',
                            text: 'Please verify your email',
                            buttons: [{
                                title: 'Send verification email',
                                handler: () => {}
                            }, {title: 'Close'}]
                        });
                        //-------------dialog-------------//
                    }
                })
        }

    },
});
```

in this case nothing writes to the console

Comment: Please add your HTML template

Comment: I just used <v-dialog/> and it works nice

Answer (score 3):

@imcvampire's answer is perfect, but if you have any doubts and want an example here it is:

https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/demo/client_side_rendering/src/components/SizeModal.vue

In vue-js-modal.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using plugin.

`v-dialog` does not currently support listeners. It is a very thin wrapper for `modal`, more like example really. I think the solution for your problem will just to use modal directly with all its features.

Answer (score 1):

You can set function in `v-modal` event:

```
<v-dialog @before-open="beforeOpen" @before-close="beforeClose"/>
```

And you define 2 methods:

```
methods: {
  beforeOpen() { console.log('open') },
  beforeClose() { console.log('close') }
}
```

Comment: OK, I wrote this `<v-dialog @before-open="beforeOpen" @before-close="beforeClose"/>` and add `methods:{ beforeOpen: function () {
            console.log("open")
        },
        beforeClose: function () {
            console.log("close")
        },}` to main parent Vue instance, however nothing happend

Comment: Can you share me your full code? You can use jsfiddle!

Comment: -1: Listeners like `before-open` and `before-close` are not supported for `v-dialog`! They works only with `v-modal`. OP was asking about dialog.